# weektodo app is not loading on starting up the pc with kubuntu os

Tags: kubuntu

I have recently installed weektodo app and selected in it's settings for it to be launched on start up but it is not happening

Comment: You've not told us your release, and details on the *app* you're asking about may also be helpful as a search shows it's likely not a Ubuntu repository app (ie. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=weektodo&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

Comment: Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-57-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-7400 CPU @ 3.00GHz
Memory: 15.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 630.

Comment: weektodo app version 2.0.0

Comment: Are you using the .AppImage file ? It is common for this to happen with this type of files, if that is the case you can try using the .deb or installing from the Snap Store.

Comment: Okay I will try to understand what do you mean by what you have stated as I am new to kubuntu and finding my way around after using windows for years.

Comment: The notifications do appear when I start the PC and icon appears on the task bar.